# Flash Builder item renderer shows correct amount but no data

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm having trouble getting data out of an API into my item renderer. What the application simply has to do is search for movies using an api and then showing the results of this using an item renderer.

The connection with API always works as i look in my network tab in flash builder and see the data come in. Also the item render shows the correct amount of fields coming in ( ex.: if i search for a movie an get 4 results returned, it shows 4 white boxes from the item renderer ) however it won't show the data. I'm trying for it to show the titel.

main mxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Button;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

        import classes.MovieSearch;
        import classes.Movie;

        public var http:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        [Bindable]public var acMovies:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {

            txtSearch.addEventListener(FlexEvent.ENTER, search);

        }

        protected function search(event:Event):void
        {
            if(txtSearch.text == "")
            {
                //var top100:Itunes = new Itunes();
                //top100songs.dataProvider = top100.getSongs();

            }
            else
            {
                var movieSearch:MovieSearch = new MovieSearch(txtSearch.text);
                movieResults.dataProvider = movieSearch.search();
                //lblFullTitle.text = "Search results for: " + txtSearch.text;
            }



        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:VGroup width="1090" height="90%" gap="30" paddingTop="30">
    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="35" gap="60" horizontalAlign="right" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:HGroup width="100%" height="35" gap="20" horizontalAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle">

        </s:HGroup>
        <s:TextInput id="txtSearch" x="635" y="3" width="225" height="25" text="Search...">
            <s:filters>
                <s:DropShadowFilter distance="0" blurX="8" blurY="8" angle="310" alpha="0.75"/>
            </s:filters>    
        </s:TextInput>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:Group width="100%">
        <s:DataGroup id="movieResults" itemRenderer="customComponents.MovieRenderer" width="100%" contentBackgroundColor="#ffffff">
            <s:layout>
                <s:TileLayout horizontalGap="60" verticalGap="30" requestedColumnCount="5" />
            </s:layout>
        </s:DataGroup>
    </s:Group>
</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

the currently simple movie class

```
package classes
{
public class Movie extends Object
{
    public var title:String;

    public function Movie(title:String)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }   
}
}
```

the movieSearch class

```
package classes
{
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

public class MovieSearch extends Object
{   
    private var url:String;

    private var result:ArrayCollection;

    public function MovieSearch(keywords:String)
    {
        result = new ArrayCollection();
        url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=7f182385c9030e466efebf258c9a5f37&query="+ keywords;

        var request:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        request.url = url;
        request.showBusyCursor = true;
        request.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, setInfo);
        request.send();
    }

    public function setInfo(ev:ResultEvent):void{
        var json_result:Object = JSON.parse(ev.result.toString());
        json_result.results.splice(0, 1);
        for each (var results:Object in json_result.results){

            var newMovie:Movie = new Movie(results.original_titel);

            result.addItem(newMovie);
        }
    }

    private function strReplace(str:String, search:String, replace:String):String {
        return str.split(search).join(replace);
    }

    public function search():ArrayCollection {
        return this.result;
    }
}

}
```

and as last the item renderer , ( NOTE: I get a warning at the label near the end of the code : Databinding wont be able to detect assignemtns to title )

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
            dataChange="validateNow();"
            creationComplete="itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
            autoDrawBackground="false">
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>
<fx:Declarations>

</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import classes.Movie;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Bindable]
        public var movieData:Movie;

        protected function itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            movieData = data as Movie;

            //lbl_more.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, parentDocument.moreInfo(songData));
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="hovered"/>
</s:states>

<s:BorderContainer styleName="bc_song" width="170">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="12" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Group>
        <s:filters>
            <s:DropShadowFilter distance="0" blurX="8" blurY="8" angle="310" alpha="0.75"/>
        </s:filters>
        <!--<s:Image width="170" height="170" x="-4" y="-4" source="{movieData.image}"/>-->

    </s:Group>
    <s:Label width="170" text="{movieData.title}"/>

</s:BorderContainer>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Thank you in advance for taking a look at my problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with how data bindings work.

'[Bindable]', when applied to a non-primitive objects, will make the binding apply to the object when the binds are applied, the bindings will not move when the reference changes. So:

```
    [Bindable]
    public var movieData:Movie;//this creates a null or undefined object, 
                               //anything binding to this will be stuck 
                               //referencing this null object

    protected function itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        movieData = data as Movie;//once this line is applied, any future binds 
                                  //will link to this but all the UI object are 
                                  //already bound to the old one
        parentDocument.moreInfo(songData));
    }
```

The way around this is to use `[Bindable] get/set functions`.

EG:

```
private var _movieData:Movie;

[Bindable]
public function get movieData():Movie
{
    return _movieData;
}
public function set movieData(value:Movie):void
{
    _movieData = value;
}
```